# "this" in javascript objects with closures behaving inconsistently

Tags: javascript, html, this, scope

So, this is probably answered somewhere on this site, but I can't find it, if it is.

I'm having trouble figuring out why one of my `this` references inside functions seems to be resolved when I create the object, and one when I call the function that has the reference inside it. Here's some code:

```
function MyObj (name) {
    this.locked = false;
    this.name = name;
    this.elem = null;
    this.func1 = function () {
        if (this.locked) return;
        /* code that changes this.name here */
        this.elem.innerHTML = this.name;
    };
    this.func2 = function () {
        this.locked = !this.locked;
        if (this.locked) this.elem.className = "locked";
        else this.elem.className = "unlocked";
    };
}

var myObjGlobal = new MyObj("foo");

function callFunc1 () {
    myObjGlobal.func1();
}
```

Then I have a function that is called on document load:

```
function onLoad() {
    var myElem = document.getElementById("myElem");
    myObjGlobal.elem = myElem;
    myElem.onclick = myObjGlobal.func2;
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = callFunc1;
}
```

I've made sure all my html elements have the right ids. When I click `myButton`, I get no errors. However, when I click `myElem`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined`.

Why is the first `this` set when I call the function, and the second `this` set when I create the object? (Or so it seems?)

here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Kbvz/) showing the problem (with the given example code).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myElem.onclick = myObjGlobal.func2;
```

This doesn't do what you think inn JavaScript.  It doesn't give you `func2` with the object "attached" to it in any way; it just gives you `func2`.  When it gets called later, it's called as a method of `myElem`, so that's what `this` is.

This is a gigantic and awful wart in JS.   :)

You can either wrap it in another function:

```
myElem.onclick = function() {
    myObjGlobal.func2();
};
```

Or use `.bind`, which does effectively the same thing, and which is supported *almost* universally nowadays:

```
myElem.onclick = myObjGlobal.func2.bind(myObjGlobal);
```

Note also that assigning to `onclick` is a little rude, since you'll clobber any existing click handler.  You may want [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Thank you Eevee! This solved my problem. Also good call on the addEventListener. I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

```
myElem.onclick = myObjGlobal.func2;
```

This loses `myObjGlobal` entirely; `myObjGlobal.func2` is just a function, with nothing tying its `this` to anything. In JavaScript, the `this` of a function is determined when it’s called, not when it’s defined. This is a fantastic and useful feature of JavaScript that’s much more intuitive than, say, Python. When `myElem.onclick` is called, it’ll be called with `this` bound to `myElem`.

[`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is a utility to do what you’re doing with `callFunc1`, by the way:

```
myElem.onclick = myObjGlobal.func2.bind(myObjGlobal);
```

Comment: Thank you minitech! I'd argue that it's much more confusing than Python's way of doing things, but as a long time Python user, I'm biased.

Comment: @GailTerman: I just edited that part in to counter Eevee’s. =)